# How to list pipes used by a process with a bash command

Tags: linux, pipe, named-pipes, diagnostics

Is there a  way to list pipes used by a running linux process (e.g. given its pid or process name) and to determine their used capacity?

Something like:

```
lspipes -l -p pid
```

resulting in something like:

```
[rw]  descriptor  size  name
```

where rw is the pipe end type and size is its used capacity

Or something similar

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) `ls -l /proc/pid/fd`

This will list the pipes

```
lr-x------ 1 prabagaran prabagaran 64 Sep  5 23:01 14 -> pipe:[57729]
l-wx------ 1 prabagaran prabagaran 64 Sep  5 23:01 15 -> pipe:[57728]
lr-x------ 1 prabagaran prabagaran 64 Sep  5 23:01 16 -> pipe:[57731]
lr-x------ 1 prabagaran prabagaran 64 Sep  5 23:01 17 -> pipe:[57730]
```

2) `lsof | grep 57731`

```
wineserve 3641 prabagaran   76w     FIFO        0,8       0t0   57731 pipe
winedevic 3651 prabagaran   16r     FIFO        0,8       0t0   57731 pipe
```

These are the pipe information related to the given process id.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really think there's such a command. You can try the following:

```
lsof -p <PID> | grep "FIFO"
```

Where `<PID>` stand for the process id. Probably there's a `lsof` switch to select only pipes and avoiding the `grep`, but I cannot find it in the man page right now.

It should give you something close to what you're looking for.

Comment: FIFO [stands for "First In, First Out"](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156)

Comment: @TML, I know... But he didn't need to change it in the command as he's supposed to do with PID!:D that's what I meant!

Comment: @Zagorax I attempted tp clear that up by quoting the literal string and and using pointy brackets for the metasyntactic variable.